# Cравнение дат разных форматов в python

Tags: python, дата, python-2.x

У меня есть 2 даты в виде строк. Зная изначально формат дат я бы сравнил так:

```
import time
date1 = "1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM" # дата формата "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p"
date2 = "1/1/2016"             # дата формата "%m/%d/%Y"
format1 = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p"
format2 = "%m/%d/%Y"
if time.strptime(date1, format1) > time.strptime(date2, format2):
   pass
```

Как я могу их сравнить если изначально не знаю формата дат?

Comment: Не зная формат - видимо, никак

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [dateutil.parser](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as dt_parse
```

Демо:

```
In [145]: dt_parse('1/1/2013 12:01:01 AM')
Out[145]: datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)

In [146]: dt_parse('1/1/2013 12:33:33 AM')
Out[146]: datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 33, 33)

In [147]: dt_parse('1/1/2016')
Out[147]: datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0)

In [148]: dt_parse('2017-05-10')
Out[148]: datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 10, 0, 0)

In [149]: dt_parse('28.02.2000')
Out[149]: datetime.datetime(2000, 2, 28, 0, 0)
```

дальнейшее сравнение дат проблем вызвать не должно

Comment: Для дат `06/05/88` и `12/01/04` возвращает не то что я ожидаю)

Comment: @andreymal, а что вы ожидаете? `dt_parse('06/05/88', dayfirst=True)` ? Можно еще так: `dt_parse('12/01/04', yearfirst=True)` или `dt_parse('12/01/04', yearfirst=True, dayfirst=True)`

Comment: Если `dayfirst=True`, то тогда я получаю не то для двух совершенно других дат `06/05/88` и `12/01/04` :D

Comment: Ну можно наверное построить нейронную сеть и пытаться угадать что вы имеете в виду указав дату `'01/02/03'` - через какое то время она возможно научиться угадывать что у вас на уме... ;-)

Comment: Спасибо, это то что надо, а на  пришлось написать свой костыль :)